# in_the_loop() issue with custom query

Tags: wp-query

I wanted to add specific class to all posts within loop using `post_class` and `in_the_loop` check but I can't get it working. From what I saw the function `in_the_loop` only check the global `$wp_query` and not the current one.

Is there any function to retrieve arguments of currently active query and not the global one?

Comment: What's the problem that adding the class solves? This sounds like an X Y problem

Comment: If you're not checking for the main query, then why do you need `in_the_loop()`? There's no case where `post_class()` wouldn't be in a loop, so what are you actually checking?